# Cannot connect to SQL Server after fresh install until reboot

Tags: sql-server, sql

I must be missing something. We install SQL 2014 Exp/ADV as part of our install routine. After it's installed, we try to connect to it and do the rest of what we need to do.

We used to use SQL 2005, and we were able to connect immediately after the install.

However, now it seems we get an error, and I have discovered that everything is fine after a reboot.

Any ideas on what service/command or whatever to get it going so we don't have to reboot?

Comment: Can you post the error that you're getting?

Comment: Have you checked to see if the relevant services are actually running right after the installation is done?

Comment: We need more information. Post the logs related to the event, as well as a list of running services. You might even find that doing so will reveal the problem to you. Services.msc will probably reveal that it's simply not started, since a reboot fixes it.

Comment: Answering my own question - use net start to start the service.